# Acessar JSON que o conteúdo é um objeto - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, json

Estou "puxando" um json no meu código cujo conteúdo é um objeto dentro de um array.
Meu objetivo é pegar cada atributo(noticia e titulo noticia) do objeto e inserir no html. Porém o retorno que tenho no navegado é : [object Object]

O JSON:
[{"noticia":"https://www.moneytimes.com.br/banco-central-ira-acelerar-aumento-do-juro-para-1-ponto-percentual-avalia-itau/","tituloNoticia":"Banco Central irá acelerar aumento do juro para 1 ponto percentual, avalia Itaú"}]

JS

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost/scraping/res.json', function(response){



const texto = document.querySelector('[data-link-noticia]');
const cont = document.createElement('a');

cont.innerHTML = response
texto.appendChild(cont);
})
```

tentei de várias formas, mas na minha condição de iniciante no assunto não consegui resolver. Se alguém puder ajudar, agradeço

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Quando você recebe o JSON pelo metodo getJSON, ele vem como um objeto javascript. Para seu conteúdo ser renderizado na tela, precisa ser convertido para string.
Para converter você pode usar a função nativa do JS:

```
JSON.stringfy(response, null, 2);
```

Repare que os parametros extras é só para formatar a string e não vir tudo em uma linha só.

Para mais informações sobre acesse:
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: Deu certo,
muito obrigado pela ajuda!